# Best theorically way to integrate some standalone apps into a web environment?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, geopackage

I've developed some python standalone apps that now I want to integrate into a web environment in order to make them more user friendly for my workmates, whom aren't used to CLI and the command shell. I've thought in remaking those apps as Django apps, using the Django REST framework, but I'm not sure if that way is the theoretically correct given the REST API meaning. For giving some examples, one of my apps takes some geometries from a geopackage, which is a kind of compact format for transferring geospatial information that could acts as a database for itself, and does some QA processes in order to ensure the geometries and data quality. Another of my apps takes some more geometries from the same geopackage and converts them into shapefiles or CAD files.

In brief, my question is that it is theoretically correct to remake those apps as Django apps, using the Django REST framework, or maybe exists another options or framework that are more suitable to what I want to approach.

Comment: Question is opinion based https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my personal experience, Django is everything you need and more. Best part of Django I feel is the db access. Its flawless when it comes to accessing database in Django. So you have nothing to worry about Django.

Another option is Flask. Flask is very simple and handy. Flask is more like a module rather than framework. You can make it in few lines of code. But simplicity comes with some down sides. The database access have no structure of its own.

Bottom line is that pick Django if you need to access database with complex queries. Without the requirement for a database, i would go for Flask.